# SQL Server 2016 Admin privileges restriction

Tags: sql-server

We have a requirement to restrict admin privileges of sysadmin on SQL Server 2016.

1. The sysadmin can install patches
2. The sysadmin can take backup
3. The sysadmin should NOT be able to READ data in tables. This is a GDPR requirement

Comment: Don't give anyone that role and you'll be OK. There's no `sysadmin` account, that's a role. Just *don't* assign that role to people unless they really really need it

Comment: we have 5 sysadmins maintaining around 300 sql server instances

Comment: You cannot prevent system administrators from reading any data -- any restriction you apply can simply be undone by them. The only recourse you have is making sure they can't *do* anything with the data -- that is, encrypting it. This is what [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) is designed to solve. Alternatively, per @Panagiotis, give no *humans* this privilege (i.e. have patches and backups handled by services that can do that and only that, and audit all access to those).

Comment: @SriniSydney so remove the role from them. It's only 5 people. Give the `db_backupoperator` to the people that need it. Give the `securityadmin` to the people that need it. There's also `setupadmin` for patches, assuming you mean Service Packs and CUs. Some of those roles can be assigned per server, some per database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , If your assign someone the role of SecurityAdmin they can change themselves to a sysadmin. Anyway non the less this is not a GDPR requirement. Yes GDPR states that people who don't need access shouldn't have it but if a sysadmin is needed to maintain a server this is a justified reason.

Comment: @Tom which is why SQL Server has other features for this. No, it's not a GDPR requirement to prevent DBAs from reading data - it's not that simple. GDPR requires proper design and proper roles. You can't just disable sysadmins and say `I'm GDPR-compliant` because you'll be as exposed as when you started.

Comment: @Tom. first *don't* give that role.  Just *don't* give those roles to everyone, not even every DBA. Do you want to prevent everyone from reading the data without permission? Encrypt it and/or mask it. Even then the requirement doesn't apply to *all* roles. That's not enough though - you need to enable the *appropriate* amount of auditing. And even then, you need to use proper retention policies. Even with encryption, if you keep data for 10 years when you should only keep them for 1 year, you aren't compliant

Comment: Let's say you remove the `sysadmin` role and nobody is now a security admin. Can the *backup operator* read the backup or restore it on a different server? Oops. That's why backups can be encrypted too. Arguably, that's *more* important than preventing DBAs for reading data - the "live" data is protected by the server, permissions, audits. The backups just sit on some tapes or offline storage server. Some low-paid consultant may even upload them to an unprotected S3 bucket

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I totally agree and I am not saying everone should be a sysadmin (Far from it) everyone should have the least amount of access needed. However what I am saying is not giving people sysadmin because of GDPR is just incorrect and in certain scenarios the sysadmin role is appropriate :).

Comment: @Tom oops, I thought the exact opposite (facepalm)

Comment: A leading database does not have any "proper" options of security roles. Really big gap here

Answer (score 0):

you can't restrict sysadmin from "viewing" data , Always-Encrypted feature can help with this....with specific tables that have "sensitive data in columns".

Regards,
Emad